Why execution of messages in queue not trigger Process
I'm using the SW.PrimitiveTypes library to handle consuming items in rabbitmq.
And I have an ASP.NET Core project which consumes messages from a queue.
I publish some message from rabbitMQ management panel and debugging hits the beginning of constructor, but it does not continue to the Process method of it - why not?
public class CreateOrderConsumer : IConsume<CreateOrderEvent>
{
    public CreateOrderConsumer()
    {
        // debugging hits here..
    }

    public async Task Process(CreateOrderEvent createOrderEvent)
    {
        // but not here..
    }
}

There is no exception anywhere in app, it simply does not proceed to "Process" as it does normally..
Here is the config file of the project:
public static WebApplication ConfigureServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.UseNamespaceRouteToken())
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore).
        AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddEPApi(builder.Configuration, new EpApiOptions
    {
        SubDirectory = builder.Configuration["SubDir"],
        SwaggerOptions = new SwaggerOptions
        {
            AddFluentValidationRulesToSwagger = true,
            Description = "The following Swagger file contains all the end points for EP Web Shipping API",
            Title = "EP Web Shipments API",
            Version = "v1",
            IncludeXmlComments = true,
            XmlCommentsFileName = "EP.Web.Shipments.API.xml"
        }
    });
    
    builder.Services.AddScoped<RequestContext>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    builder.Services.RegisterPrimitiveTypesDataResolvers(new PrimitiveTypes.DataResolving.DataResolvingOptions()
    {
        ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxx"),
        BackOfficeConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxx")
    });

    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
 
    builder.Services.AddBus(configure =>
        {
            configure.ApplicationName = "xx";
        }, builder.Environment.EnvironmentName);

    builder.Services.AddBusPublish();
    builder.Services.AddBusConsume();

    builder.Services.AddScoped<RequestContext>();

    return builder.Build();
}
 

What might cause this how can I trace the issue?

Please make sure that the consumer is correctly registered with the message bus and then share the test results.

@JasonPan thanks for answer but it shows following error; "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Assembly' because it is not a delegate type"

Hi TyForHelpDude, since you are using 3rd package SW.Bus, and there is no github issue under this project. I guess it's may not popular. If you want get better experience, you can consider to use MassTransit.
